# Woocommerce get_post_meta custom field in webhook

Tags: wordpress, webhooks

I'm trying to pass 3 custom fields in a WooCommerce order.created webhook.

The webhook works correctly; I get the custom fields in the payload, but anytime I try, I cannot get a valid output from the `get_post_meta` data function.

Am I missing something?

Below is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_webhook_payload', 'sendsikkert_woocommerce_webhook_payload' );

function sendsikkert_woocommerce_webhook_payload( $payload, $resource, $resource_id, $id ) {

    $order  = wc_get_order( $resource_id );

    $ssmail = get_post_meta( $order , '_billing_myfield12' , true );
    $cvrnr  = get_post_meta( $order , '_billing_myfield4' , true );

    $payload['order']['Sendsikkert_email'] = $ssmail;
    $payload['order']['CVRNR']             = $cvrnr;

    return $payload;
}
```

Whenever I try to populate the two custom fields result in this at the end of my payload:

```
"Sendsikkert_email":false,"CVRNR":false,
```

I've used the Woo checkout manager from Visser labs to add the the fields; they are in the post meta data.

How do I get a `get_post_meta` result into these 2 fields in my payload?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?